# symfony2 multiple nested forms prototype

Tags: forms, symfony, prototype, nested-forms

I want to include a collection type inside another collection type.
It should look like this: [image]

Using just one collection works fine, but I need to edit the prototype of the outer form, so it renders the prototype of the inner form for each line.

Any ideas how could I do that? Also what would be the best way to save

EDIT:
Now I am trying to render the prototype of the nested form:

```
  <ul class="characteristics-container" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.characteristics.vars.prototype)|e }}" data-prototype-options="{{ form_widget(form.characteristics.options.vars.prototype|e ) }}">
                    {# iterate over each existing tag and render its only field: name #}
                    {% for characteristic in form.characteristics %}
                        <li>{{ form_row(characteristic.name) }}</li>

                        <div class="characteristics-options">
                            {% for opt in form.characteristics.options %}

                            {% endfor %}                     
                        </div>


                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
```

It gives error in `form_widget(form.characteristics.options.vars.prototype|e`

```
Method "options" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in
```

I tried characteristics[0], and it says the key doesnt exist

Here are my form classes:

**PromotionType (the base form)**

```
$builder              
            ->add('characteristics','collection', array(
                'label'         => 'Caracteristicas',
                 'type'         => new PromotionCharacteristicType(),
                 'allow_add'    => true,
                 'allow_delete' => true,
                 'by_reference' => false
            ))
```

**PromotionCharacteristicType**

```
 $builder
            ->add('name',NULL, array('label'  => 'Nome'))
            ->add('options', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new PromotionCharacteristicOptionType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,      
                'prototype' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))                       
        ;
```

**PromotionCharacteristicOptionType**

```
 $builder
            ->add('name',NULL, array('label'  => 'Nome')) 
        ;
```

The first level prototype, works fine.

Comment: Hi all. I am trying to develop similar forms, to create (new) and edit nested entities. I developed a toy Symfony 3.1 bundle for entities A 1:m B 1:m C. It seems to work. I appreciate if you check and suggest how to improve/rewrite it. See at https://github.com/mario6097/SimpleBundle. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### forms and prototype

You need to keep two prototypes from different collections. Symfony offers to store them in a data-prototype attribute of div tag, which wrap the collection. In your situation it`s very inefficient. So you can just render it by hand in empty div somethere

Example you have characters form

```
class CharacterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('opts', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new OptionType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'prototype_name' => '__opt_prot__'
        ));
        $builder->add('char_desc', 'text');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'char';
    }
}
```

Then create form that has characters collection

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('chars', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new CharacterType(),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype_name' => '__char_prot__'
    ))
    ->getForm();

    # example data
    $form->setData(
        array(
            'chars' => array(
                array('options' => array(), 'char_desc' => 1),
                array('options' => array(), 'char_desc' => 2),
            ),
        )
    );
```

and get prototypes

```
<div
    id="prots"
    data-prototype-opt="{{ form_widget(form.chars.vars.prototype.children['opts'].vars.prototype) | e }}"
    data-prototype-char="{{ form_widget(form.chars.vars.prototype) | e }}"
>
</div>
```

And then render collection like in this [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items) or override collection_widget block

```
{% for char in form.chars %}
    {{ form_row(char.char_desc) }}
    <label for="">opts</label>
    {% for opt in char.opts %}
        {{ form_row(opt.text) }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### how to save it

Use nosql database if you can. Or use [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model for relation databases. But if you do not need to search through the options, or sort them, you can store a serialized array in the database and use the doctrine type `array`

Comment: I have a problem with data-prototype2: Key "0" in object (with ArrayAccess) of type "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, set up new version of symfony and see the error. Update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Only in your answer I found how to reach the prototype in nested forms: `data-prototype-opt="{{ form_widget(form.chars.vars.prototype.children['opts'].vars.prototype) | e }}"`.

Comment: Some strange behaviour: nested form prototype is available only before form rendering! Maybe some bug in my code, maybe I will save some else time for researching :)

Comment: @brpaz : can u please tell me how your javascript, html and formtypes finally are created? I am struggling with the same, as you can see here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514638/embedded-collection-in-embedded-collection-add-button-symfony-2-8 and also i tried creating a fiddle for my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/lexhartman/s5Lrtjtf/ (use the 'click me' button to update the form and to see the add button for the child forms. The problem is that when a child form is inserted in the 1st parentform and a 2nd parent form is added you can no longer add childforms to the 1st parent form... and also a lot of other wrong coded functions... So i would like to see how you ended up solving this problem. Thanx in advance!

Comment: @Lex,  did you fix your fiddle?

Comment: The order of prototypes is critical: the most nested one should go first, and then - its parents (in reverse order). Otherwise child prototype will go to the parent, and you'll get an empty string in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Alexey B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044355/alexey-b)'s answer, I don't usually seem to need to use `prototype.children['opts']` in order to be able to access the prototype for the collection. I just use `prototype.<collection_name>` as follows:

```
<div
    id="prots"
    data-prototype-opt="{{ form_widget(form.chars.vars.prototype.opts.vars.prototype) | e }}"
    data-prototype-char="{{ form_widget(form.chars.vars.prototype) | e }}"
>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because Twig uses dot notation to access associative array index, object get method of the same name, or  object property. Allowing `prototype.opts` to access `prototype['opts']` or `prototype->getOpts()` or `prototype->opts`.