# PHP Symfony Forms How to access Properties in nested objects

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I am creating several forms with **Symfony** and the **FormBuilder**. Normally I provide a flat object that holds all properties the form needs to access. This works fine. The form fills the object with the correct values and I can send it as json to a webservice wher it is processed (so I don't access a database at all).
But in several cases I got nested objects from the webservice that have to be updated or I have to send nested objects (as json) to the service and I wonder if it is possible to access properties of nested objects within the form.

Normally you do

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($myObject)
->add('myProp', 'text', array(
    'label'=>$this->get('translator')->trans('my Property')
))
```

But in my case **myObject** holds another object where some properties are located. So I would need to do something like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($myObject)
->add('nestedObj.myProp', 'text', array(
    'label'=>$this->get('translator')->trans('my Property')
))
```

But unfortunately this does not seem to work. Is there another solution to deal with nested objects and forms?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this previously answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487129/symfony2-multiple-nested-forms-prototype)

Comment: Have you read through the forms manual?  Nested objects are very common.  You just need to make a form type specific to each entity type.  ->add('nestedObj',new NestedObjFormType())

Comment: Just a note but you don't need to use the translator. You can just write the property and translator will work automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much. As symfony is still new to me that was very good help.

Answer (score 7):

Dots are not allowed in field names (the reason for this lies in the details of the HTML specification). However, you can override the "property_path" option to customize the used property path:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($myObject)
    ->add('myProp', 'text', array(
        'label' => $this->get('translator')->trans('my Property'),
        'property_path' => 'nestedObj.myProp',
    ))
```