# Symfony2 Nested Collections and the Prototype

Tags: php, symfony

I have 3 nested form in Symfony2. I won't get into all the code here beacuse it can be long. I'm just gonna show an example of what I want to do here.

So, let's say that `Category` has a `Product` and the Product has a `Tag`.
Each one of them would be a reusable `AbstractType`.

This would be the code for the **CategoryType** (I will leave out `allow_add`, `allow_delete`, and `by_reference` for increased readability).

```
$builder->add('product', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new ProductType(),
    'prototype' => true,
    'prototype_name' => '__product__'
));
```

This would be the **ProductType**

```
$builder->add('tag', 'collection', array(
    'type' => TagType(),
    'prototype' => true, 
    'prototype_name' => '__tag_name__'
));
```

**TagType** is not really important here. What I want is render the prototype for these collections in Twig in two `divs` like this...

```
<div class="ResourceAttributePrototype" data-product-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.product.vars.prototype)|e  }}"></div>

<div class="Prototype" data-tag-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.product.vars.prototype.children['tag'].vars.prototype)|e }}"></div>
```

The problem is that the first prototype is render in the data attribute, but the second is an empty string. Why?

Also, if anyone has a better idea of how to render nested form collections, Im all ears. I found [a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487129/symfony2-multiple-nested-forms-prototype) that i followed but it does not work.

Comment: Did you find this possible solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487129/symfony2-multiple-nested-forms-prototype

Comment: Well, not yet. The only thing i figured out is that the child prototype is rendered inside the parent prototype. That is, when you render form_widget(form.product.vars.prototype)|e, inside it there will be the nested collection. The only way that I see to make this work is javascript. Create the parent prototype, extract the child from the parent and create the child. I'm doing that right know so I will post a solution after I'm done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply render out the children first, this problem goes away.

Example from one of my projects:

Render these prototypes first:

> campaignForm.campaignRows.vars.prototype.children['campaignTexts'].vars.prototype
>       campaignForm.campaignRows.vars.prototype.children['featuredItems'].vars.prototype
>       campaignForm.campaignRows.vars.prototype.children['campaignImageCampaigns'].vars.prototype

Then the parent:

> campaignForm.campaignRows.vars.prototype

Works for me, hopefully it works for you too. I assume the children are set as rendered internally somehow which causes the problem you have.

Comment: No. I get Object of class Symfony\Component\Form\FormView could not be converted to string exception. But if it worked for you, it has to work for me.

Comment: Bear in mind that the above is just pseudo code showing the order, not anything you'd use directly. The solution posted above by Pi Wi more or less does pretty much exactly the same thing I do, it *should* work for you.

Comment: It's also worth noting you can prototype an entire macro if you need a complex repeatable layout.

Comment: I didn't see the link he posted but I found that one before I posted this question and it does not work. Right know, I'm just working with what I got. Prototype inside a prototype. I'm on a deadline so I can't experiment. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i figured it out.

This was a project that I inhereted. It had its own form themeing and that themeing made nested form collections be rendered inside own another.

So if anyone sees this, check your form theme, if you made it custom.

The answers above all work.